# Rubymine: overcommit gem is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rubymine, ruby-overcommit

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project that uses overcommit to perform various checks during the commit process. Everything works fine on the command line, I can commit, change branches, push and pull with no problem. However, when I try to perform the same actions in Rubymine, I get the following error:

```
This repository contains hooks installed by Overcommit, but the `overcommit` gem is not installed.
Install it with `gem install overcommit`.
```

Despite the fact that the overcommit gem is installed in the RVM gemset for this project.

My setup is as follow:

- Rubymine 8.0.3
- RVM 1.26.11
- Ruby 2.2.3
- overcommit 0.29.1

Comment: in the rubymine preferences did u set the Ruby SDK and Gems prefs to the correct RVM ruby and gemset?

Comment: Yes, they are both set correctly. I can even see the overcommit gem in the list of gems Rubymine is currently using.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue today. The problem is that Rubymine does not run in the same environment as your terminal and does not know anything about RVM, nor gems installed under RVM.

**Update as of 09/2023**: The original solution (kept below for reference) works unreliably and installing gems into the system ruby is not recommended and sometimes not even possible. Notably, there has been an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17869) open at JetBrains which includes several tips for handling this problem but, unfortunately, still no official solution. We use one of the options mentioned there, a **custom git script**, without any problems in all our projects. I'll describe it here:

So the problem is that when running a git hook, such as Overcommit, while making a commit in the RubyMine IDE does not share the same ruby environment as the terminal. Luckily, **RubyMine allows to customize the git command** so we can pass it a script that will ensure the proper ruby environment is used.

The script for RVM might look like the one below and say that we save it to `bin/rvm-git.sh` inside our project:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Run git commands in context of current RVM ruby, if possible,
# see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17869 for more info.
if [ -d .git ]; then
  rvm-exec . /usr/bin/git $@
else
  /usr/bin/git $@
fi
```

As a side note, we switched from RVM to [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) a long time ago, so we actually use the following script stored at `bin/chruby-git.sh` but the principle is the same:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Run git commands in context of current chruby ruby, if possible,
# see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17869 for more info.
if [ -d .git ]; then
  chruby-exec 3.2.2 -- /usr/bin/git "$@"
else
  /usr/bin/git "$@"
fi
```

Be sure to make the script executable (`chmod a+x <script_file>`).

Now, open RubyMine settings, go to Version Control ⟶ Git and point the **Path to Git executable** input to the script you just created. Optionally, check the "Set this path only for the current project" if you like.

[image: Setting up custom git command in RubyMine]

Now you should be able to use Overcommit or any other ruby-based git hook under RubyMine without problems.

##### Original solution - use with caution

You need to **install Overcommit into the system ruby environment** which is most easily done by installing it under root:

```
$ sudo -i
$ gem install overcommit
```

After you do that, you should be able to make git commits in Rubymine again. However, note that Rubymine won't display Overcommit's warnings in the VCS console, nor anywhere else as the Rubymine's git plugin simply ["eats" everything](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206722985-Git-integration-commit-hooks) from STDOUT / STDERR unless Overcommit makes the git commit fail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this solution did not work for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me (on phpstorm)

Comment: No longer works as of MacOS 12, in 2022. System Ruby is not writeable, even with sudo.
https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/you-don-t-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-6-0-directory/

Comment: ```Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break
this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Could not locate Gemfile``` -- this doesn't work

Comment: I added a much better solution (custom git script) to the answer.