# How to implement a custom Rubocop rule for checking git branch naming convention?

Tags: ruby, git, naming-conventions, git-branch, rubocop

For example, I need to check the correctness of git branch naming - it should contain ticket ID similarly to this:

```rb
module Rails
  class GitBranchName < RuboCop::Cop::Cop
    MSG = "Use correct branch name by pattern  '{TicketID}-{Description}'. TicketID is mandatory for linking with the task tracker and should be at least 2 digits"

    def on_send(node = nil)
      branch = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

      return if starts_from_ticket_number?(branch)

      p "Current branch name: '#{branch}'"

      # add_offense(node, severity: :warning)
    end

    private

    def starts_from_ticket_number?(name)
      gitflow_prefixes = [:bug, :bugfix, :feature, :fix, :hotfix, :origin, :release, :wip]

      name.match?(/(#{gitflow_prefixes.join('/|')})?\d{2,}/)
    end
  end
end
```

But as I see, Rubocop processes only text nodes and checks only text lines. So, is it possible to define a rule that will be run only once to check one custom check not related to code but only to business logic?

Also I've created discussion here https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/discussions/10470

Comment: why not use git hooks instead of a Rubocop rule? So that you'll be able to avoid pushing unallowed branch names.

Comment: I've tried to add git hooks, it works well only for cmd terminal, but for such tools like SmartGit it doesn't work. Here question that is related to git hooks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066529/rubymine-overcommit-gem-is-not-installed

Comment: There really isn't much to discuss for your particular use case. What you want here is a pre-commit hook.  A good answer has been provided below. The question you've linked to in your comment is a system configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up adding a custom script for checking branch naming and adding it to the CI pipeline:

`bin/git_check`

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

# :nocov:
class GitBranchNameValidator
  MSG = "Use correct branch name by pattern  '{TicketID}-{Description}'. TicketID is mandatory for linking with the task tracker and should be at least 2 digits"

  class << self
    def call
      branch = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.split("\n").first

      return if starts_from_ticket_number?(branch)

      puts "Current branch name: '#{branch}'"
      puts MSG

      exit 1
    end

    private

    def starts_from_ticket_number?(name)
      gitflow_prefixes = [:bug, :bugfix, :feature, :fix, :hotfix, :origin, :release, :wip]

      name.match?(/(#{gitflow_prefixes.join('/|')})?\d{2,}/)
    end
  end
end

GitBranchNameValidator.call
# :nocov:
```

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, `rubocop` analyzes *code*, either as AST nodes, or lines of text / entire files. Therefore, the answer is: it might be possible, but don't do this.

I'd recommend keeping these things separate, e.g. having `rake check` that runs `rubocop` and also runs `rake check_commits`, and the later checks your git commits.